# How to check if the version of npm package is outdated(on npm server)?

Tags: npm

I know I can use below to see what my packages are outdated.

```
npm outdated
```

But how can I know what's the WANTED version of a package that I didn't install?

I also found below and it shows every version of their package but it does not show what versions were deprecated.

```
npm view XXX version
```

Comment: in the documentation there is everything that can be done "https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated" I have not found anything that's right for you

Comment: Thanks. @GianfrancescoAurecchia hm.. It's strange that there is no way to get that..

Comment: I try to see if there is any additional package to get what you are looking for but I do not think I will be lucky

Comment: you cant try use "npm ls"? tell me if that's what you were looking for

Comment: try to see this "https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check"

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia I looked it already but it shows the packages that I installed like 'npm outdated'.

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia Please rephrase your comment, in order to avoid the impression that you are insulting somebody.

Comment: certainly less practical but ... you tried to open package.json and package-lock.json manually

Comment: Again, what I want is that I want to get information, especially 'deprecated version name' of the package that I don't install to my project. @GianfrancescoAurecchia